# Best way to handle HTTP post request based off of origination source

Tags: node.js, express, playframework

In any web framework (most likely an MVC framework), what is the best way to handle post requests differently depending on the origination page or state of the request? do we use the same post handler method but use conditionals to check for different origination of requests (maybe http referrer)? or is there a better way?

I am using Node Express which is not necessarily MVC so I don't mind something quick and dirty.

Comment: You should not rely on the HTTP `Referer` header because not all browsers will send it.

Comment: ... And it can be forged.

Comment: any alternatives to HTTP referer then?

Comment: Two controller actions that use a common form.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand that can you elaborate @LimbSoup?